# Uglyfying in r.js, but keeping the line breaks, using uglify2

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js, uglifyjs2

I am looking for a way for making r.js (RequireJS' optimization script) ugylyfying our JS-modules BUT letting the line breaks remain.
Im using uglify2 as my optimize value.

```
  optimize:                   'uglify2',
```

in my build script. I can do "optimize :  none", but i want my files to me minified, i just want to preserve line numbers.
is there an option to do that with uglify?  is there an equivalent to "closure.keepLines" for uglify2 ??

Requirejs optimization doc
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#options
https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

Answer (score 3):

You can pass this to your r.js configuration:

```
optimize: 'uglify2',
uglify2: {
  output: {
    beautify: true,
  },
  beautify: {
    semicolons: false
  }
}
```

It will not really keep the original line breaks, but rather beautify the the uglified code. The `semicolon` option will seperate statements with line breaks rather that with semicolons. There are other options to play with, you can find the all at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

I commit js files compiled by requirejs to my git repo and I found these settings work pretty well (diffs of compiled files are pretty clean).